# How can I restore a file to its original path which is saved in another file?

Tags: bash, shell

I need to restore the file to its original location by using its path name, which can be found in the .restore.info file that I created.

Here is the removal script:

```
    # did the user enter a filename
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
echo "No file was entered"
exit
fi

# warns the user if a directory and not a file was entered
if [ -d "$1" ]; then
echo "Directory name entered. Please enter file name"
exit
fi

# if the correct file name is entered then display file deleted
if [ ! -f "$1" ]; then
echo "$1 Does not exist"
exit
fi

# finds inode of a file to avoid files with the same name
inode=$(stat -c '%i' $1) 2>/dev/null

# shows the path of the file
path=$(readlink -f "$1") 2>/dev/null

# prints name of the file and its path in the .restore.info file
echo "$1_$inode:$path" >> ~/.restore.info 2>/dev/null

# warns the user if they enter this script as an argument
if [ $1 = "remove123" ]; then
read -p "Are you sure you want to delete remove? y/n:  " answer

#if yes, then remove the file otherwise do nothing
if [[ $answer = y ]] ; then
        mv "$1" deleted/"$1"_"$inode" 2>/dev/null
        echo "$1_$inode:$fixedPath" >> ~/.restore.info 2>/dev/null
else
        exit
fi
fi

#moves to deleted dir
mv "$1" deleted/"$1_$inode" | cut -d "  " -f 1 2>/dev/null
```

And heres what I have so far in my restore script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#go to deleted directory
cd ~/deleted

# did the user enter the argument
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
echo "No file was entered"
exit
fi

# if the incorrect file name is entered then display file deleted
if [ ! -f "$1" ]; then
echo "$1 Does not exist"
exit
fi

#move restored file to the original path   
original=$(grep "$1" .restore.info | cut -d ":" -f2 )

mv $1 $original
```

**Update:** I managed to figure out how to get the original path name from the file in .restore.info. I used the grep and cut commands which work on the command line, but not in my script. I get the error: `grep: .restore.info: No such file or directory`. Any ideas why?

Comment: I suggest to try `dirname`.

Comment: dirname did not retrieve the original path, but rather the .restore.info filename. The command $cat .restore.info would list the files with their original paths that I sent there when I removed them e.g. file1:home/user/file1. I just want the path after the colon when the user types in "file1".

Comment: Something like `sed 's#[\:]*:\(.*/\).*#\1#' "$1/.restore.info"` ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us a few lines from the restore file and what you expect to happen when reading them. It is not easy to extrapolate what the file will look like by reading your code.

Comment: I found a way to get the path name but still cant get my script to work. I have updated the post for more information.

Comment: Your "delete" script sends the info about the deleted file to `.restore.info` in the `HOME` directory:  `echo "$1_$inode:$path" >> ~/.restore.info 2>/dev/null` but your "undelete" command is looking in the local directory: `original=$(grep "$1" .restore.info | cut -d ":" -f2 )`.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your first script correctly, what you're doing is writing the full filespec (path & filename) to the `.restore.info` file, prepended with the filename and inode of the file.  You then move the file to a "deleted" directory.

To "undelete" the file, you'll want to move the file back to the directory from whence it came, per the filespec in your `.restore.info` file.

In that case, you don't need to do a readlink of the `.restore.info` file; you want to simply get the correct path for the file in question out of it.  So, something like this will do the trick:

```
restinfo=`grep "$1" ~/.restore.info`
echo $restinfo

filespec=${restinfo##*:}
echo $filespec

path=${filespec%/*}
echo $path

delname=${restinfo%:*}
echo $delname
```

The first line loads the `restinfo` variable with the full line from the restore file.  Then we grab everything after the colon (`:`) and put that in filespec.  That will be the original path plus the file name. The next bit grabs the path portion of that, but since you're renaming the file when you "delete" it, we'll need to use the full filespec.  So we don't really need "path", but what the heck.  Lastly, we grab the name of the deleted file (the filename plus the inode).  Now we have all we need to "undelete" the file:

```
mv deleted/$delname $filespec
```

I did some tests to check that this works.  First I created a script to build the delete file, then another to parse the info needed to restore it.  Here are the two scripts:

```
tmp1()
{
  # finds inode of a file to avoid files with the same name
  inode=$(stat -c '%i' $1) 2>/dev/null

  # shows the path of the file
  path=$(readlink -f "$1") 2>/dev/null

  # prints name of the file and its path in the .restore.info file
  echo "$1_$inode:$path" >> test-restore.info 2>/dev/null
}


tmp2()
{
  restinfo=`grep "$1" test-restore.info`
  echo $restinfo
  filespec=${restinfo##*:}
  echo $filespec
  path=${filespec%/*}
  echo $path
  delname=${restinfo%:*}
  echo $delname
}
```

Note that I changed the name of the restore file for my test.  Here is the output:

```
> rm test-restore.info

> tmp1 testin.txt

> tmp1 testout.txt

> cat test-restore.info
testin.txt_30412509:/home/sinasnet/test1/testin.txt
testout.txt_30412507:/home/sinasnet/test1/testout.txt

> tmp2 testin.txt
testin.txt_30412509:/home/sinasnet/test1/testin.txt
/home/sinasnet/test1/testin.txt
/home/sinasnet/test1
testin.txt_30412509

> tmp2 testout.txt
testout.txt_30412507:/home/sinasnet/test1/testout.txt
/home/sinasnet/test1/testout.txt
/home/sinasnet/test1
testout.txt_30412507

>
```

First I deleted the restore file to make sure it was empty.  Then I "deleted" two files (which just loaded the restore file), did a `cat` on the file, and then did the second script to get the info needed to "undelete" the files.

There are a couple of issues with your delete script, btw.  First, you're moving the deleted file to a "deleted" directory under whatever directory the user is in.  There may not be such a directory and, if there is, you're assuming the user will be in the same directory when they want to undelete the file.  That's a lot of assumptions.  It might be better to use a specific "deleted" directory, such as ~/deleted instead.

Next, I'm not sure what your intent was with the `cut` command on your move is, but I don't think it will do much of anything.

Lastly, you load a `path` variable, but don't use it.  And the comment says you're showing the path, but really it's just loading it.

Anyway, I hope this helps.